# AD FS login with Django fails with Error code 364

Tags: adfs, adfs3.0

I am trying to connect my Django app to AD FS.
*Note: All domain names used a fake/internal*

I can login fine (`/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedSignOn.aspx`)
[image]
BUT not after integration with an app

Connector Lib used: django-saml2-auth https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth

When I try to log in I am redirected to

`https://win-sh2hfr5t2r9.dtest.com/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=nZLNTsMwEIRfJfI9cWL112oqFaqKSAWiJlQVF%2BQmLrGU2MW7Ke3b46TAgUMP3Lzrmc%2BzK880hHzRYqU38qOVgN65qTVw145JazU3ApQrRSOBY8GzxeOasyDkR2vQFKYmv4botkEASIvKaOItfo73RkPbSJtJe1KFfNmsY1IhHjml0ZQF0WgSRMGYTyIKoqnZm3BBqSiAEm%2FpsiotOsrVA870qbQPFasOdojMToMSnSooTENFeQBad8ZkGRNV%2Bsddyvan1R522TjfnjcuVgLQykQDCo0xYSEL%2FZD5bJJHQz4Y8cH0lXjp99h3SpdKv98eeX8VAX%2FI89RPn7OceFtpoc%2FsBGQ%2Bc2vj%2FbvWWxnbCLxN7Dou%2FKGXcqlR4YV4tOOE%2FMldJsvU1Kq4%2FIOGVmhQjtkD6d%2BPMf8C`

AD FS Error Log below

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
  <Provider Name="AD FS" Guid="{2FFB687A-1571-4ACE-8550-47AB5CCAE2BC}" /> 
  <EventID>364</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000001</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-02-28T16:10:03.589483500Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>63</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-9500-0080010000D0}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4064" ThreadID="3820" /> 
  <Channel>AD FS/Admin</Channel> 
  <Computer>WIN-SH2HFR5T2R9.dtest.com</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-2884057814-3114364144-2287182707-1113" /> 
  </System>
<UserData>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ActiveDirectoryFederationServices/2.0/Events">
<EventData>
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>System.Xml.XmlException: ID4125: An error occurred reading XML data. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2NameIdentifier.set_Value(String value) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadNameIDType(XmlReader reader) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadNameIDType(XmlReader reader) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Saml2AssertionSerializer.ReadIssuer(XmlReader reader) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadCommonElements(XmlReader reader, SamlMessage message) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolSerializer.ReadAuthnRequest(XmlReader reader) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlBindingSerializer.ReadProtocolMessage(String encodedSamlMessage) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlBindingSerializer.CreateFromNameValueCollection(Uri baseUrl, NameValueCollection collection) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpRedirectSamlBindingSerializer.ReadMessage(Uri requestUrl, NameValueCollection form) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlMessageFactory.CreateMessage(WrappedHttpListenerRequest httpRequest) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlContextFactory.CreateProtocolContextFromRequest(WrappedHttpListenerRequest request, ProtocolContext& protocolContext) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.CreateProtocolContext(WrappedHttpListenerRequest request) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.GetProtocolHandler(WrappedHttpListenerRequest request, ProtocolContext& protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler& protocolHandler) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context) System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2NameIdentifier.set_Value(String value) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadNameIDType(XmlReader reader)</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
  </UserData>
  </Event>
```

I have even added Incoming Claim Transformation
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with your service provider Metadata. Check is your enityt id, name-id format and security array is correct. As teh log suggests the issue is with your xml data, so there is some mismatch at IDP and SP end.

Comment: How do I view the xml data? like this ? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3286.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-use-fiddler-web-debugger-to-analyze-a-ws-federation-passive-sign-in.aspx

Comment: You must have provided an endpoint for your service provider data to the adfs(IDP). That's adfs identifies your server. From your service provider you check your data in your case its your application